# Nifi PutDatabaseRecord Update

Tags: apache-nifi

Enviroment
nifi 1.21.0
DB = MS SQL 2019

Can someone explain to me why PutDataBaserecord 1.21.0 when statement type= update

The processor will pass flow files to success when the PK does not exist in the DB instead of routing to fail?

unmatched Column Behavior = fail on unmatched Columns.

Short example Database has only dod_id=1. You pass a json record dod_id=2 the processor routes to success and does not insert the record. It is as if the Update Keys is only checking if there is a value in the id column and does not care if it matches any records in database.

I know there are other ways to achieve the desired result. I'm just very confused why I cannot get this processor to fail on matching id form flow file and DB.

End picture I'm trying to mimic a upsert by doing a PutDBrecord update piping all none matches to fail then running that with a PutDBRecord insert.

Input record containing dod_id=1 and dod_id=2. DB update dod_id=1 as a match and nifi fail dod_id=2 because record not in DB.

[PutDB1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raxty.png)

[PutDB2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ephqj.png)

-Work Around-
I was able to mimic it by doing the insert first which fails on primary keys then pipe fails to update. I do have a work around; Still curious why the update processor does not fail when PK does not exist.

Comment: Can you share your PutDatabaseRecord configuration? Are you specifying any Update Keys? Is your `id` column a primary key?